# Keyboard layout and charset encoding

Tags: windows, keyboard, character-encoding

How does keyboard layout (switched in Windows for e.g. by `Alt+Shift`) relates to character encoding? How to determine what charset encoding is currently used in Windows? How to know what charset encoding we'll be used if i switch keyboard layout (for e.g. from `PL` to `EN`)?

Answer (score 1):

> How does keyboard layout (switched in Windows for e.g. by Alt+Shift) relates to character encoding?

It doesn't.

> How to determine what charset encoding is currently used in Windows?

The OS and most modern programs *always* use Unicode. (For byte representation, Windows uses UTF-16, but other programs often use UTF-8... it's Unicode either way.)

Older programs (using "ANSI" mode) use an encoding apropriate for whatever encoding was sent in Regional Settings, under *"Encoding used by non-Unicode programs"*. Normally it requires a reboot to be changed (though there's an AppCompat tool to do it in a better way). Luckily you almost never need to change it.

Of course, programs like text editors can still make their own decisions on how to *write files* – e.g. even Notepad has a character encoding dropdown in its "Save as..." window.

Many other formats such as `.docx` always use Unicode.

Comment: Looks like it does, when entering the alt codes the current active layout influences the output, both with and without '0' prefix... Or, perhaps there is another reason?